# How to let a class access a private method or attribute of another class?

Tags: c++, class

Considering a class with only a private attribute like:

```
class Example
{
private:
    int number = 10;
};
```

If I create another class that contains a vector of `Example`,
is there a way to let only this class access the private attribute?

```
class ChangeExampleValue
{
public:    
    Example v[5] {*new Example,*new Example,*new Example,*new Example,*new Example};
    
    changeNumber()
    {
        for(Example e : v)
        {
            //something that let me access the private attribute "number"
            e.number*=2;
        }
    }
};
```

in this particular case the class "ChangeExampleValue" contains instances of `Example`, but I'm even interested in a solution for classes that haven't anything in common.

Comment: You can't, that's why it's called _private_. The class needs to give you access through a getter and / or setter function explicitely.

Comment: Declare `ChangeExampleValue` a `friend` of `Example`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I think the point of the question is how to make it un-private for just one specific class, in this case 'ChangeExampleValue'

Comment: @rustyx thanks, I'll do a research.

Comment: If you need to modify a value from another class, you should generally use a public function to do so. `friend` can be used when only specific classes should but in my opinion, in practice, this is often more useful for library writers to somehow have a simple main class for users while hiding stuff in complex implementation classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a friend class.

```
class B;
class A {
private:
int v;
friend class B;
};

class B {
private:
B array[5]; //B has access to A's vars
};
```

I don't suggest you use this too often because it ruines the idea of incapsulation. You could use inheritance or simply make A public, especially if it is only a data structure with no methods.